# How to add data augmentation to an object detection model (DETR) HuggingFace

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, data-augmentation

I am trying to follow the [Hugging Face DETR Tutorial](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/DETR/Fine_tuning_DetrForObjectDetection_on_custom_dataset_(balloon).ipynb) for fine-tuning in my own dataset. Here they explain that some data augmentation techniques are applied.

```
Note regarding data augmentation

DETR actually uses several image augmentations during training. One of them is scale augmentation: they set the min_size randomly to be one of [480, 512, 544, 576, 608, 640, 672, 704, 736, 768, 800] as can be seen here. 
However, we are not going to add any of the augmentations that are used in the original implementation during training. It works fine without them
```

However, I want to add more, such as zoom, hsv variations, etc.
The dataset class definition is as follows:

```py
import torchvision
import os

class CocoDetection(torchvision.datasets.CocoDetection):
    def __init__(self, img_folder, processor, train=True):
        ann_file = os.path.join(img_folder, "custom_train.json" if train else "custom_val.json")
        super(CocoDetection, self).__init__(img_folder, ann_file)
        self.processor = processor

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # read in PIL image and target in COCO 
        img, target = super(CocoDetection, self).__getitem__(idx)
        
        # preprocess image and target (converting target to DETR format, resizing + normalization of both image and target)
        image_id = self.ids[idx]
        target = {'image_id': image_id, 'annotations': target}
        encoding = self.processor(images=img, annotations=target, return_tensors="pt")
        pixel_values = encoding["pixel_values"].squeeze() # remove batch dimension
        target = encoding["labels"][0] # remove batch dimension

        return pixel_values, target
```

The preprocessor_config.json read by HuggingFace to load the model includes:

```json
{
  "do_normalize": true,
  "do_resize": true,
  "feature_extractor_type": "DetrFeatureExtractor",
  "format": "coco_detection",
  "image_mean": [
    0.485,
    0.456,
    0.406
  ],
  "image_std": [
    0.229,
    0.224,
    0.225
  ],
  "max_size": 1333,
  "size": 800
}
```

Which already includes the mean and variation for augmentation. As a new user in HuggingFace, I do not know if repeating that in the typical `torchvision.transforms.compose([])` would affect on anything, or should we discard adding it as it is already done here in the json file?
I didn't find anything similar on the Internet. It is probably a dummy question but I don't know how and where to add the augmentations. Could anyone make an example, given my situation?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have this concept wrong:

> Which already includes the mean and variation for augmentation

These values:

```
  "image_mean": [
    0.485,
    0.456,
    0.406
  ],
  "image_std": [
    0.229,
    0.224,
    0.225
  ],
  "max_size": 1333,
  "size": 800
```

are not for augmentation purposes, they are scaling factors to ensure the new data nicely fits the distribution of the pretrained data. The size and max_size is what DETR can infer at runtime (as per the paper).

To augment data, you need to do it yourself, typically using [Albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/docs/) or Torchvision transforms, as you mention. Just remember that you need to transform both the image and the annotation.

In other words, *the preprocessor receives the augmented images and annotations*.

This examples shows this nicely:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/object_detection